# Getting rid of "body" from an array content when appending it to a JSON API request payload in Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, microsoft-dynamics, azure-logic-app-standard

I'm new to Logic Apps and I think this is a basic data manipulation problem, but I have been stucked on it for few days now and I hope someone can help me.

I have an Azure Logic Apps worklow which is querying a bunch of addresses from Dataverse and it is then:

1. Parsing the JSON
2. Creating an array of addresses by getting rid of all the odata metadata and selecting only the fields that I need
3. Sending an API request to a 3rd party entity by appending the array content to the API request.

This is how the workflow looks like in this screenshot.

[image: querying part]

Unfortunately the API request I'm sending is not formatted correctly because it looks like this.

[image]

but it is expected as in this screenshot.

[image]

So basically I don't know how to append just the array content without the body, which is coming out as output of the "Select" action.

[image]

The "Select" action has been set up as in this screenshot.

[image]

I thought I had to use that action and not a compose cause some of those AddressLine fields are optional and when using a Compose action in a For Each loop, it causing the workflow failing because of the fields missing.

Anyway, any advice on how to manipulate the data properly and build the JSON API request as expected? Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

I tried also replacing the array with a string approach, but it didn't look like a clean practice, cause then I had to manipulate the string to replace some characters when appending it to the JSON payload, and when sending it to the 3rd party, for some reason, it was picking up only the first item of the list of addresses, and not all of them.

Comment: Which action you are using from Dataverse connector?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin Apologies, it's my first time creating a post on stackoverlow, and I just noticed the images where added with the text as comments, I've just fixed them. I guess you meant the Select action which is creating the object with the body: and the array in it. If you mean how I am getting the data from Dataverse, it's a list rows from Dataverse using a fetchXML query.

Comment: Which table you are using from list rows action?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I've just added a screenshot of the querying part in the main post. The table I'm using is a custom one.

Comment: Try using `Append to string variable` action, it works

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin If I use an append to string variable, then I have to manipulate the string to remove the "{body: " part at the beginning, which I did and it was ok. I then added the string to the json paylod (wrapping the string into a json() function) and it just processes the first address item, not all the addresses presents in the string.

Comment: Using append to string variable action, I am getting expected [output](https://i.imgur.com/1ve2DEA.png). I am getting this output without any string manipulation directly using the Select output

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I still get the body part, no idea why https://imgur.com/a/n27czI3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get rid of **body** parameter from **`Select`** action's output, I have used **Append to string variable** action and added `body('Select')` as  value in it.

[image]

[image]

By doing so, I am able to get the expected output without any string manipulation.

[image]